# Not-updatable child entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have such method:

```
@Transactional
public void add(User2 object) {
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, false);

    session.save(object);

    String number = generateNumber(object.getPerson().getId(), object.getPerson().getFranchise().getId());
    object.setLogin(number);
    object.getPerson().setNumber(number);
    session.update(object);
}
```

Entity User2 contains entity Person. As you see, first - I am adding a new record to a database and then I just want to update sonme fields of User2 and Person. The problem is that only User2 field are updated (HQL query is generated only for User2 entity too). How can I make it to update a Person entity too? 
Thank you

```
@Entity @Table(name="users") public class User2 implements Serializable {   
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * 
 */
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

/**
 * 
 */
@Column(name = "login")
private String login;

/**
 * 
 */
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

/**
 * 
 */
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Person2.class, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
private Person2 person;


/**
 * 
 */
public User2() { 
    this.setId(0L);
} /*getters ans setters*/ }

@Entity @Table(name="persons") public class Person2 implements Serializable {   
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * 
 */
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

/**
 * 
 */
@Column(name = "title", nullable = true)
private String position;

/**
 * 
 */
@Column(name = "firstname", nullable = true)
private String firstName;

/**
 * 
 */
@Column(name = "lastname", nullable = true)
private String lastName;

/**
 * 
 */
@Column(name = "birthdate", nullable = true)
private String birthDate;

/**
 * 
 */
@Column(name = "Notes")
private String notes;

/**
 * 
 */
public Person2() { 
    this.setId(0L);
} /* getters ans setters */ }
```

Comment: Please post your classes with relevant mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you ding it this way.Please try the following:

```
@Transactional
public void add(User2 object) {
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, false);
    String number = generateNumber(object.getPerson().getId(), object.getPerson().getFranchise().getId());
    object.setLogin(number);
    object.getPerson().setNumber(number);
    session.saveOrUpdate(object);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The problem is that object.getPerson().getId() is auto_increment value and on this stage is null

Comment: This is true, because Hibernate assigns key values only when it persist it in the session. I think you need to review all the way you are using Hibernate in your scenario.

Comment: But the problem is not there. My main problem - why it updates only User entity without updating Person? (see my first post)

Comment: If you need to get object id, do it like this: Long id = session.save(object); otherwise it will return null. because it's not assigned yet.

Comment: As you see in first piece of code: there is generateNumber method after save method. Then? this number is inserted into user's login and person's number firelds. After that - update. The problem is that user's login is being updated successfully, but person's number not.